# REST service constructor called multiple times in Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, rest, tomcat, constructor

I have a rest service developed in Java that runs on Apache Tomcat. 
This service is implemented by a class and I explicitly defined a constructor for it.
I'm load testing it and I found out the constructor is being called multiple times. Then the number of resources being allocated in the constructor is continuously increasing and probably faster than the GC's freeing resources.
I'm trying to understand the reason why the constructor is called multiple times. I suppose the service is being unloaded too fast by Apache and then it has to be created again to process a new request.
Any hint about why this could be happening?

This is just a snippet of what I have:

```
@Path("/myservice")
public class ProcessService
{
    private DBConnection conn;
    final static public String APP_ID = "MY_APP";

    public ProcessService()
    {
        System.out.println("-----------------------CONSTRUCTOR CALLED --------------------------");
        conn = new DBConnection(APP_ID);
        System.out.println("-----------------------CONSTRUCTOR CALLED-2 --------------------------");
        ...
    }
...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the normal behavior in case of a non-CDI JAX-RS application. Possible solutions for your problem:

- move your app into an EE container with CDI (e.g. JBoss) or turn your Tomcat into a CDI capable container with [Weld](http://www.lucubratory.eu/getting-weld-cdi-into-tomcat-7/) and make use of CDI scopes

  ```
  @Path("/myservice")
  @ApplicationScoped
  public class ProcessService
  ```
- refactor your app in a way that it would not cause any serious trouble if your Service was instantiated on each request. e.g.

  ```
  final static public String APP_ID = "MY_APP";
  private static DBConnection conn = new DBConnection(APP_ID);

  public ProcessService() {
      System.out.println("-----------------------CONSTRUCTOR CALLED --------------------------");
      // conn is now a static variable so the connection is created only once
      System.out.println("-----------------------CONSTRUCTOR CALLED-2 --------------------------");
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However I cannot find the ApplicationScoped annotation in package javax.ws.rs . Maybe I'm using the wrong libraries?

Comment: This is a CDI annotation, it should be in package: 'javax.enterprise.context'. Sorry I missed the part that you are using Tomcat so you don't have CDI by default...then this is totally normal, your service is instantiated on each and every request.

Comment: I've edited my answer to make it useful in case of Tomcat as well.

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to just add javaee jar to my project but it seems I need to work with J2EE to use CDI, right? Is there any other way to have persistent objects if my service is instantiated per request? What if I want to have a pool of connections?

Comment: Yes, you need either a JEE appserver like JBoss or you have to add Weld into your project as it is explained in the article I linked. For pooled connections you better use a DataSource and let your container manage it.

Comment: Thank you for all the information. Now I understand my problem and will be able to solve it. I'll come back with the solution I chose.

Comment: I followed the link and installed Weld libraries for Tomcat. Then I was able to import the class "javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped" and to annotate my class with @ApplicationScoped. However I'm still seeing the constructor is called per request.

Comment: have you also configured the xmls? web.xml, beans.xml and context.xml

Comment: Yes I did. As indicated in the link. If you say it should work, I will keep investigating. Thanks.

Comment: I just made a quick test. It works for me with Weld + RestEasy. You are probably missing the CDI Jax-RS bridge. In case of RestEasy it is: resteasy-cdi.

Comment: Just saw your comment. I'll test again and I'll come back. Thank you.